# Divide operator conflicts in overriding

Tags: c++

I had to define my own class `myDouble`  since I wanted to override default divide operation. I wanted divide by zero to give me 0 and not crash the program (my customer requirement).

Now I wanted to support `double d = myObj` where `myObj` is type of `myDouble`. Hence I created double operator() in my class. Since I also had needed to create my own divide operation. So I created `friend operator / (myDouble a, myDouble b ).`

Now compiler complains that it finds conflict in resolution which divide operator to call, my own or the system one.

What would be the right strategy for this problem solution?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is not to allow implicit conversions between `double` and `MyDouble`.   Don't supply the `operator double()` to `MyDouble`.  Any constructor of `MyDouble` that accepts a `double` also needs to be `explicit`.   If you really need to be able to store a `myDouble` in a double, provide a member function (e.g. `double to_double() const`) and use that, instead of an implicit conversion.

Comment: Note that dividing a `double` by 0 usually gives you `Inf` (or `-Inf` or `NaN`), not a crash.

Comment: @melpone - you're assuming IEEE floating point.   It is not true of other floating point representations - which do exist in the real world.   In C++, floating point divide by zero is actually undefined behaviour.

Comment: The best is not to use a conversion operator. Do it like `std::string` which explicitly does not feature an automatic conversion to `char*`. See https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ro-conversion

Comment: You mean you created *both* a member `double operator / (double)` and a friend operator?

Comment: @melpomene how can i handle Inf or NaN in code and making sure i move to next line making the lhs have value 0 ? Any suggestion as i could not find on net